# User-needs approach

Tags: user-expectation, interface

Do you think that an approach that consists of asking the user directly what their profile or sector of activity is and then refining the value proposition or directing them to a landing page that will aggregate the adapted solutions/expertise and other related content is a good practice or on the contrary does it show a flaw in the definition of personas and targets?

We sometimes see this principle on interfaces, so the idea is sometimes blown up by project managers and I have always wondered about the relevance of this practice.

You can take the section below the hero banner on this site in its French version to illustrate my point: https://www.bureauveritas.fr/

[image]

If I position myself as a user, I don't think I'd mind answering a simple question so that I'm well oriented. But I think that this already requires a minimum of commitment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts: I would not replace a conventional navigation by this pattern. But it could be a good way to provide an alternative way to bring the user to the right page.

I would not use this to rebuild the conventional navigation but to also provide a structural alternativ to the navigation. E.g. the conventional navigation could have an order logic grouped by products and the conversational navigation could be grouped by use or situation etc. This way you serve different needs to different users. But as always, this should be testet with real users in order to finde out if they find the desired content better this way.

Comment: Interesting point of view. I completely agree with you about offering this only as an alternative/complementary navigation. I was wondering if this could be considered as poor UX and what are the arguments for or against it. Maybe "conversational navigation " is the right keyword I was looking for